# Is there a tool/app that can show download throughput and frame rate of video streaming

Tags: video, streaming, buffer, frame, lag

Is there a tool that shows frame rate , buffer ,lag & UL/DL throughput of a video streaming or if a stored video is being played back on the client laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I built StreamOrNot to tell you if your video would stream depending on the network conditions (which you can modify with browser devtools):

https://dougsillars.github.io/StreamOrNot/

It'll give you Buffering and the UL/DL and size of the video.